# How to use PHP shell_exec upload GitHub?

Tags: php, github

I want to use shell_exec to push to git server,How could i do?

```
<?php
    echo shell_exec('git add .');
    echo shell_exec('git commit -m"update"');
    echo shell_exec('git push origin master');
?>
```

> [master 9471163] update Committer: Unprivileged User Your name and email address were configured automatically based on your username and hostname. Please check that they are accurate. You can suppress this message by setting them explicitly. Run the following command and follow the instructions in your editor to edit your configuration file: git config --global --edit After doing this, you may fix the identity used for this commit with: git commit --amend --reset-author 1 file changed, 5 insertions(+) create mode 100644 shell.php

Answer (score 0):

Issue this in console to set up global username and email for git:

```
git config --global user.email "yourmail@address.com"
git config --global user.name "Your name"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also run command as another user with `su`:

```
su - username -c "command"
```

->

```
echo shell_exec('su - username -c "git add ."');
echo shell_exec('su - username -c "git commit -m \"update\""');
echo shell_exec('su - username -c "git push origin master"');
```

Replace "username" with your unix login name.